# Python incorrect result

Tags: python

I have a small doubt.When running the following code in python I am not getting the desired result.Can anyone explain why?

```
x,temp=[4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23],[]

for y in x[:-1]:temp.append(max(y,x[x.index(y)+1]))

print temp
```

Output for the above code is:-

```
[62, 98, 98, 27, 23, 70, 98, 98, 93, 93, 53, 60, 60, 62]
```

But it should be-:

```
[62, 98, 98, 27, 23, 70, 98, 98, 93, 93, 53, 60, 60, 23]
```

The only error I am getting is at the last element 62 as it should be 23 .Can anyone explain the reason?

Comment: When y is the final element in your list (4), `x.index(4) = 0`. It's the duplication of 4 in your list with the use of `index` that causes the problem.

Comment: That's the exact error and thankyou for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As asongtoruin mentions in the comment your code doesn't do what you want because the `.index` method finds the first matching element in the list. So when it's testing the final 4, it _doesn't test it against the 23, it tests it against the 62 following the first 4 in `x`.

Here's a better way.

```
x = [4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23]

temp = [max(u,v) for u,v in zip(x, x[1:])]
print(temp)
```

**output**

```
[62, 98, 98, 27, 23, 70, 98, 98, 93, 93, 53, 60, 60, 23]
```

FWIW, it's a good idea to avoid using `.index` unless you really need it because it has to scan linearly through the list looking for matches, so it's not very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The end index of the slice is exclusive. Your value is -1 which means the last element which is exclusive - so it skips it.

Change `x[:-1]` to `x[:]` which will go through every element.